# HttpOnly Cookie in new Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, cookies, httponly

I'm working with a 3rd party authorization API that requires multiple API calls with a session token that needs to be updated on each call in a MERN stack.

When performing the first call, I can see the cookies I need returning under Network > Cookies for the corresponding call. I can also see the related set-cookie headers under Network > header for the call. The cookies are flagged with HttpOnly and Secure. From my understanding, this means that I cannot use javascript to access these cookies and they will not be stored in document.cookie. However, I need to use these cookies in the response from the first call, in the second API request.

How can I use the first API response HttpOnly cookies in the second request?

Answer (score -2):

It depends on how you configure your api call.  If you are using javascript native fetch, set `credentials` to "include".  If you are using something like axios, it has a config setting `withCredentials: true`.  This tells the request to send your cookie with the request, and your server will get it from the cookie.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

https://github.com/axios/axios